# How do I stop the checkbox appearing, so it is slider only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm using slider 3 from here:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles

It is the "On/Off" Slider, I have copied the HTML and CSS. Everything is working as it should, however on my webpage the "Checkbox" is still visible along with the On / Off slider, please see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey6CQ.jpg

CSS I used is:

```
/* SLIDE THREE */
.slideThree {
    width: 80px;
    height: 26px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.slideThree:after {
    content: 'OFF';
    font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
}

.slideThree:before {
    content: 'ON';
    font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #00bf00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.slideThree label {
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 20px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.slideThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    left: 43px;
}
```

HTML I Used is:

```
<!-- Slide THREE -->
<div class="slideThree">    
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" />
    <label for="slideThree"></label>
</div>
```

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: We're going to need the HTML rendered in the browser and your code to help :)

Comment: I'll supply the code now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
.yourSliderClassHere input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

See the sourcecode on the website you mentioned.

Comment: Hey, I've added: .sliderThree input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
} still showing checkbox :(

Comment: typo? slide <-> slider ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
<style> .slideThree input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```